# How to attach a Task<List<T>> to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, async-await

Trying setting up my SQLite data and populating from database to Lists database will return an `async Task<List<T>>` that holds values I need to assign to my collection list. I get error code CS1503 :

```
Using System.Collections.Generic;
Using SQLite;

public Task<List<Reward>> rewards;
public List<Reward> rewardsList;
RewardDatabase reward;

private async void GetRewards()
{
    rewards = reward.GetItemsAsync();
}

async void AssignIt()
{
    rewardsList = await rewards;
}
```

I am trying to get values from `rewards` to a collection I can access from `rewardsList`.

Comment: Because your function is Async, you can simply use 'await' as such : await reward.GetItemsAsync();

Comment: Not an SQLite question.

Comment: You may want to read about `async`/`await` in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model

Comment: What's your code in `GetItemsAsync()`?

Comment: When you have an error, please include in question **the *complete* error text**, instead of simply saying "error code CS1503". This gives more details about what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `await` when calling `async` methods

```
rewardlist = await reward.GetItemsAsync();
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't solve the issue, the system is trying to convert the Task<List<reward>> to List<Reward>

Comment: The root problem is that you are not using async/await correctly.  There may be other lines of code that need to be changed fix your overall problem, but that is absolutely the issue.

Comment: @DeckerAyers - if this doesn't fix it, then there likely is a problem **inside the task returned by GetItemsAsync()**. Add that code to question. And put a breakpoint in GetItemsAsync. Step through the code. It might be easier to figure out, if you make a separate method, that contains the code run by that task. Step through that new method.

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem with `GetItemsAsync()`.

You can refer to the [Store data locally in a SQLite.NET database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows#update-the-app-with-visual-studio). It involves how to attach a `Task<List<T>>` to a `List<T>`.

`GetNotesAsync()`:

```
public Task<List<Note>> GetNotesAsync()
        {
            //Get all notes.
            return database.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
        }
```

Attach a `Task<List<T>>` to a `List<T>`:

```
collectionView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetNotesAsync();
```

Wish it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score -3):

In this case, you could just use `task.Result` to get `List<T>` (in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task?source=recommendations)):

```cs
// remove `async`
private void GetRewards()
{
    rewards = reward.GetItemAsync();
    rewardList = rewards.Result;
}
```

or use `async/await`:

```
private async void GetRewards() 
{
    rewards = reward.GetIemAsync();
    rewardList = await rewards;
}
```

But first solution looks very strange, maybe `RewardDatabase` was provide like `GetItem()` or some other synchronized function?